# Ionic popup template accesing app.js $scope

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've made a popup in my Ionic app. This popup follows a template I made..

RadioTemplate.html

```
 <script id="RadioTemplate.html" type="text/ng-template" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
<label>
<p>Fill in catergory name</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Rent">
</label>
<br />
<br />
<p>button check is: {{button1}} </p>
<div class="row">

<div class="col col-25"><button class="button button-outline button-button1" id="button1in" nh-show=button1></button></div>
<div class="col col-25"><button class="button button-outline" id="button2in"></div>
<div class="col col-25"><button class="button button-outline" id="button3in"></div>
<div class="col col-25"><button class="button button-outline" id="button4in"></div>
</div>


<div class="row">

<div class="col col-25"><button class="button button-outline" id="button5in" ng-show="button1"></div>
<div class="col col-25"><button class="button button-outline" id="button6in"></div>
<div class="col col-25"><button class="button button-outline" id="button7in"></div>
<div class="col col-25"><button class="button button-outline" id="button8in"></div>
</div>


<div class="row">

<div class="col col-25"><button class="button button-outline" id="button9in"></div>
<div class="col col-25"><button class="button button-outline" id="button10in"></div>
<div class="col col-25"><button class="button button-outline" id="button11in"></div>
<div class="col col-25"><button class="button button-outline" id="button12in"></div>
</div>
</script>
```

As you can see I am trying to ng-show certain buttons on this popup. For this, I need it to read the $scope of button1.

app.js

```
.controller('TodoCtrl',  function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {
$scope.button1 = true;
});
```

But as you can see, it can't read the {{button1}}! 
It can read it in my main HTML file (The template is also in my main HTML file)

Solution:

Previously I had this. I forgot to add scope: $scope!

```
$scope.popUpColors = function(){
$scope.popUp = $ionicPopup.alert({
title: 'Colors!',
templateUrl: 'RadioTemplate.html',
 });
 };
```

After adding it, it looked like this.

```
$scope.popUpColors = function(){
$scope.popUp = $ionicPopup.alert({
title: 'Colors!',
templateUrl: 'RadioTemplate.html',
scope: $scope
});
};
```

Comment: I dont see any issue in your code, `button1` is defined under the `todo`  controller, so it should be accessible inside template.

Comment: Try keeping RadioTemplate.html script in same HTML template where {{button1}} is accessible.

Comment: That is the problem. the RadioTemplate is inside my index.html (Where it can read button1) but for some reason, inside the template it can't read it anymore

Comment: I figured it out. In my app.js I had the function which triggered the popup. I forgot(stupidly..) to include $scope! I'll edit my popup function in here for future problem solving.